# How to create IBAction from UISegmentControl?

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, ibaction

I am dealing with `UISegmentControl` in my project. I am able to create outlet & outlet collection of `UISegmentControl` with the help of drag & drop. But not able to create `IBAction` of Segment Control.
I think I am missing very small thing. Any Idea how should I proceed now?
For more clarity you can refer this screenshot.[image]

Comment: Can you show up some code ?

Comment: I just want to drag & drop & create IBAction of this segment control. After this ill start writing code inside IBAcion function.. but I am not able to drag & drop only...

Comment: just delete and add again once

Comment: @PriyankaKanse  Right click on SegmentControl in storyboard, in popup there is events list. Choose "Value Changed" and drag it to controller (file owner)'s header file and write appropriate method name to it.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code in your `controller` :

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
@IBAction func segmentedControl(sender: AnyObject) {

    if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {

        // Do something with the first button
    }
    else {
        // Do something with the second button, etc...
    }
}
```

Then drag it from your `code` to your `segmentedControl`

Comment: I tried it.. it is working finely with IBOutlet. But its giving me an error while dealing with IBAction

Comment: Ok, try to delete all the link you've made by drag and drop your segmented control, and retry, it should work

Comment: I just got the solution. Actually i am using  cocoapod in my project to integrate third party frameworks. So i was writing my code in .xcworkspace file instead of .xcode file. IBoutlet was supporting in both .xcode & .xcworkspace  but IBAction supports only in .xcode file. Afterwords i created action in .xcode file & it  reflected in .xcworkspace also. But direct IBAction from segment control in .xcworkspace is not supporting I dont know y this is happening? But Thank you so much for the feedback answer :)

Answer (score 3):

This is same as button actions the only difference is instead of selecting TouchUpInside or other button events you should use "**ValueChanged**"

UISegmentControll will respond to value changed action

Comment: I just got the solution. Actually i am using  cocoapod in my project to integrate third party frameworks. So i was writing my code in .xcworkspace file instead of .xcode file. IBoutlet was supporting in both .xcode & .xcworkspace  but IBAction supports only in .xcode file. Afterwords i created action in .xcode file & it  reflected in .xcworkspace also. But direct IBAction from segment control in .xcworkspace is not supporting I dont know y this is happening? But Thank you so much for the feedback answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to click assitant Navigator in the top corner right hand side to open Implementation file then drag segment control to implementation file after the @implementation directive that will pop the dialog screen.

[image]

Comment: I knew it.. but in pop up its just showing me two options i.e. outlet & outlet collection. Its not showing me action as an option inside the connection

Comment: Check you are dragging to the correct viewController class that belong to storyboard

Comment: Also make sure you're dragging to the `@implementation` block.

Comment: I just got the solution. Actually i am using  cocoapod in my project to integrate third party frameworks. So i was writing my code in .xcworkspace file instead of .xcode file. IBoutlet was supporting in both .xcode & .xcworkspace  but IBAction supports only in .xcode file. Afterwords i created action in .xcode file & it  reflected in .xcworkspace also. But direct IBAction from segment control in .xcworkspace is not supporting I dont know y this is happening? But Thank you so much for the feedback answer :)